# Moodle set cooling off period for reattempt

Tags: plugins, settings, moodle

I am building a quiz portal using Moodle. For my quiz, I have set a passing grade of 7.0. If the user fails in 2 attempts, I would like to display a message like "Please brush up your skills and reattempt after 2 weeks". The user must be allowed to reattempt only after 2 weeks of time.

Is there any settings or plugin to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the "Enforce delay between later attempts" option.  Located in the "Extra restrictions on attempts" section in the quiz settings.
[image: Enforce delay between later attempts option]

Based on Moodle's explanation:

> If enabled, a student must wait for the specified time to elapse
> before attempting the quiz a third time and any subsequent times.

Let me know if that helps.